# Show metadata from photos (image sequence)?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, image

Is it possible to read metadata from an imagesequence? I am doing a timelapse and thinking about using Blender for putting it all together. Need to read the date from metadata and show it.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something such as generic file creation time which is available for all files?   Do you mean the date the picture was taken, similar to say the type of camera, as in jpeg information?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to show the date the photo was taken. Probably just year and month.

Comment: Repeat question.  Do you want?  A. Generic File Info or B. jpeg information?. .... Warning this may not be a blender question.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/57317/editing-jpeg-exif-properties  ..... is this relevant?

Comment: Ok, I will write elaborate. Blender has many useful tools. Now I am using it to put together a timelapse, mostly using the Video Sequence Editor, maybe also the compositor. My question is, would it be possible to extract the date from the file currently showing in the image sequence, and show it?

You with me now?

Comment: I hope someone steps in to remove the fog.  I suggest you get any tool which produces in text format the information you want ... filename ... date.  Then the question will reduce to .... How can a list of information be the contents of a Blender Text object? Can the names of files be correlated? (Yes)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python and [getctime](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-os.path.html#l2h-2178) to get your desired data.

```py
try:
    mtime = os.path.getctime(file_name)
except OSError:
    mtime = 0
last_modified_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(mtime)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know nothing about python in Blender. How can you display the date in VSE or sequencer?

Comment: I don't think Blender as any builtin mechanism for reading and displaying metadata directly, at least not readily available or exposed to end users through it's UI. Blender did become capable of writing (and reading I think) EXIF metadata to some image file formats (like JPEG and PNG) a few versions ago, where it saves render statistics in it's metadata, so maybe through some Python wizardry you can read other EXIF information from it's files but I don't know how to, I am not much into coding myself.

Comment: Perhaps the result of the getctime call could fill a text object in another scene, then the rendered output from that scene could be overlayed onto the image seq in the VSE? Not sure if there is a loop issue or a delay however?